# Regex for processing Python

Tags: python

`Data = {[\\[/key:// [value] //]//]}`

Form the above data I want to get dictionary (key : value)  pair .

But one more thing is data may be in any format

For example : `Data = {[key : [value]]} or { \ key : \ value }`

Whatever the format is all I need is key value.

So how can I get that dictionary key value pair.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Key and value pairs Start with Letters or words:

```
>>>import re
>>>data = "{[\[/key:// [value] //]//]},{[\[/key1:// [value1] //]//]}{ \ key3 : \ value3 }"

>>>list_keys_values = re.findall('([a-z]*[a-z]\w)',data)

>>> list_keys_values
['key', 'value', 'key1', 'value1', 'key3', 'value3']

grouped = [ list_keys_values[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(list_keys_values),2)]

>>> grouped
[['key', 'value'], ['key1', 'value1'], ['key3', 'value3']]

dicitionary = dict(grouped)

>>> dicitionary
{'key1': 'value1', 'key3': 'value3', 'key': 'value'}
```